# flicker a screen of iphone ipad in given frequency

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, flicker

I want my app to blink/flicker in the screen hopefully showing a video or photos, in a given exact frequency,  like from 2 Hz to 70 Hz, could go black, of with a heavy dark filter?

Comment: You might need to put a health warning on your app then, in case it causes problems for people with epilepsy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a scheduled timer with interval of 1/70.

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0/70.0 target:self selector:@selector(flicker) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Then, in your flicker method, change the alpha property of your view.

Alex